# HttpURLConnection executing two times

Tags: java, android, xml, httpconnection

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to make a request to server and save some data in the `Database`, but when I make the request it executes two times which adds two identical rows in the database.

Note: I am making the same request to the server from `iOS` as well and it works perfectly this only happens on `Android`

This is the code where I make the request:

```
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream outputStream = (OutputStream)httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name" ,"UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8")+"&"
        +URLEncoder.encode("user_id" ,"UTF-8") + "=" + user_id+"&"
        +URLEncoder.encode("manager_id" ,"UTF-8") + "=" + manager+"&"
        +URLEncoder.encode("company_id" ,"UTF-8") + "=" + company+"&"
        +URLEncoder.encode("user_role" ,"UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_role ,"UTF-8");

bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();

InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

final char[] buf = new char[256];

final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (true) {
    int length = reader.read(buf);
    if (length == -1) break;
    sb.append(buf, 0, length);
}

reader.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: You are closing the output streams in the middle. Can you test the same thing, but closing them in the end (at the same time as you close input streams). Also call httpURLConnection.disconnect() in the end. iOS and Android use a different socket mechanism. Probably it is related with this fact. Also before calling the reader, do a flush on your output stream. Other point to check is how fast is the server responding? Not sure if Android sends an automatic retry after some time in case the server does not respond.

Comment: @Besart which version of android do you use?

Comment: Make sure that the code, is not inside in a  Android Lifecyle Hook.

Comment: I would put some debugging logs or attach the debugger to see if this code is being run twice from somewhere, like a lifecycle hook.

Comment: @pringi In this case closing the output stream is benign. Calling `disconnect()` disables the connection pool. It isn't likely to help anything.

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection automatic retry mechanism causes the request to be repeated twice.

**Problem Analysis And Positioning**

HttpURLConnection uses a Sun private HTTP protocol implementation class: `HttpClient.java`
The key is the following method of sending a request and parsing the response header:

```java
569       /** Parse the first line of the HTTP request.  It usually looks
570           something like: "HTTP/1.0 <number> comment\r\n". */
571   
572       public boolean parseHTTP(MessageHeader responses, ProgressSource pi, HttpURLConnection httpuc)
573       throws IOException {
574           /* If "HTTP/*" is found in the beginning, return true.  Let
575            * HttpURLConnection parse the mime header itself.
576            *
577            * If this isn't valid HTTP, then we don't try to parse a header
578            * out of the beginning of the response into the responses,
579            * and instead just queue up the output stream to it's very beginning.
580            * This seems most reasonable, and is what the NN browser does.
581            */
582   
583           try {
584               serverInput = serverSocket.getInputStream();
585               if (capture != null) {
586                   serverInput = new HttpCaptureInputStream(serverInput, capture);
587               }
588               serverInput = new BufferedInputStream(serverInput);
589               return (parseHTTPHeader(responses, pi, httpuc));
590           } catch (SocketTimeoutException stex) {
591               // We don't want to retry the request when the app. sets a timeout
592               // but don't close the server if timeout while waiting for 100-continue
593               if (ignoreContinue) {
594                   closeServer();
595               }
596               throw stex;
597           } catch (IOException e) {
598               closeServer();
599               cachedHttpClient = false;
600               if (!failedOnce && requests != null) {
601                   failedOnce = true;
602                   if (httpuc.getRequestMethod().equals("POST") && (!retryPostProp || streaming)) {
603                       // do not retry the request
604                   }  else {
605                       // try once more
606                       openServer();
607                       if (needsTunneling()) {
608                           httpuc.doTunneling();
609                       }
610                       afterConnect();
611                       writeRequests(requests, poster);
612                       return parseHTTP(responses, pi, httpuc);
613                   }
614               }
615               throw e;
616           }
617   
618       }
```

In the code on lines 600 - 614:

failedOnce is false by default, indicating whether it has failed once. This also limits sending a maximum of 2 requests.
httpuc is request related information.
The default value of retryPostProp is true, and the value can be specified by command line parameter (-Dsun.net.http.retryPost=false).
streaming: Default false. true if we are in streaming mode (fixed length or chunked).

Use the Linux command socat tcp4-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr system:“sleep 1”!!stdout to establish an HTTP server that only receives requests and does not return responses.
For a POST request, after the first request is sent, the parsing response will encounter an early end of the stream, which is a SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server. After parseHTTP captures it and finds that the above conditions are met, it will retry. The server will receive the second request.

**Solution**

1. Disable the retry mechanism of HttpURLConnection.
   Via launcher command parameter -Dsun.net.http.retryPost=false
   or code to set System.setProperty("sun.net.http.retryPost", "false")
2. Use the Apache HttpComponents library.
   By default, HttpClient attempts to automatically recover from I/O exceptions. This automatic recovery mechanism is limited to a few exceptions that are considered safe.

HttpClient will not attempt to recover from any logical or HTTP protocol errors;
HttpClient will automatically retry methods that are considered idempotent;
HttpClient will automatically retry methods that still fail to send HTTP requests to the target server. (For example, the request has not been fully transmitted to the server).

Comment: The question is about Android. But Android uses OkHttp and not any Sun private HTTP protocol implementations.

Comment: But he uses `HttpURLConnection` to get the HTTP request. Please check his question in detail. Thank you!!! @rmunge

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` is an abstract class. The code in the question uses URL.openConnection() to get an instance of `HttpURLConnection`. For OpenJDK and Oracle Java runtime engines this will return an instance of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` which makes use of the `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient`. But on android the returned object is an instance of `com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler`. So your explanation is right for Java applications, running on OpenJDK or Oracle JREs, but not for Android.

Answer (score -1):

Android uses [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) to implement the functionality of `HttpURLConnection`. OkHttp silently performs retries under certain circumstances:

> ... OkHttp perseveres when the network is troublesome: it will silently
> recover from common connection problems ...

The library had several issues in the past with unexpected retries including POST requests (for a good summary see [here](https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace)). Even latest development branch of Android seems to use a more than 5!!! years old version of OkHttp (see [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:external/okhttp/CHANGELOG.md;bpv=1;bpt=0)). So, it is very likely that Android's version does not have any of the relevant bug fixes. There is also no simple way to access the internal OkHttp client instance and explicitely disable retries.

So, you have two options:

- A) Use a newer version of OkHttp directly in your app instead of relying on
  `HttpURLConnection`
- B) Try to workaround the problem:

It seems that some of the retries are not performed when the content of a POST request is not buffered internally by OkHttp. You can avoid internal buffering by either setting an explicit content lenght through [setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode-long-) or by enabling chunked streaming through [setChunkedStreamingMode(0)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode-int-).These workarounds seem to avoid at least some of the retries (see comments on [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37036206?pli=1) ticket), but there is no guarantee that this will avoid all kinds of retries.

From a security perspective, I heavily recommend to follow approach A) and **not** use Android's `Http(s)URLConnection`. As mentioned before, the Android open source project seems to use a completely outdated OkHttp version, that even does not receive any security fixes (at least not from the official OkHttp project).

Be aware, that most smartphone manufacturer use a closed-source fork of the Android open source project. They may use different versions of third-party libraries or even use a different HTTP client library under the hood.

Comment: Unreliable connection to the Web server, not the database. The OP's code does not attempt to connect to a database.

Comment: @user207421 the question mentions that the HTTP request finally triggers an insert into a database. It's totally clear that the HTTP request will not be handled directly by a database. But the question does also not mention what components are between the HTTP client and the database (proxy, web server, applicaction server, messaging ...).  With "unreliable connection to the database" i mean everything between the android app and the database. I adapted the wording to avoid misunderstandings.